How to bypass useEffect dependency for custom hook?
Here's my sample code:
const { getConversionList, conversionList } = useConversion();

useEffect(() => {
  getConversionList();
}, []);

useConversion is a GraphQL resolver hook, I'm getting Linting error to add dependency. But if I add dependency then it is an infinite rendering.
How can I safely bypass it?
Tried adding dependency by caused infinite rendering. I want useEffect to run only once on load hence added [] as dependency

Do you really need this useEffect?
you can try
useEffect(() => {   getConversionList(); }, [getConversionList]);
if you need it on initial rendering will be something like this I guess
const { conversionList, loading, error } = useConversionsList();

@ZhivkoNikolov but in that case on every re-render that useConversionList() function would be called, not only on initial rendering

if you haven't wrapped your "getConversionList, conversionList"  inside the useMemo hook. can you wrap it

You Might Not Need an Effect

well then you will need cache setup, so the data will be fetched only when needed
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/overview/
Talking from experience: reading the Docs can save you a lot of time

Since you tagges this apollo-client - are you sure you are not abusing useLazyQuery for something that you should use useQuery instead? You should probably never use a useEffect like this.

You can ensure that useEffect runs only once by using a useRef hook to track if the effect has already run:
const { getConversionList, conversionList } = useConversion();
const hasFetchedRef = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!hasFetchedRef.current) {
    getConversionList();
    hasFetchedRef.current = true;
  }
}, [getConversionList]);



Disable the linting rule for this specific line.
Use a ref to store the function so it doesn't change on each render.

import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
const { getConversionList, conversionList } = useConversion();
    
const getConversionListRef = useRef(getConversionList);
    
useEffect(() => {
  getConversionListRef.current();
}, []);


You may try add this below line. // eslint-disable-next-line
For your code snippet.
const { getConversionList, conversionList } = useConversion();
useEffect(() => {
  getConversionList();
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);


Created a custom hook like this and used it to resolve. I see several articles on it
import { useEffect } from "react"

export default function useEffectOnce(cb) {
    useEffect(cb, [])
}

useEffectOnce(()=>{
  getConversionList();
});

